# Export handout with notes using org-mode and beamer

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, beamer

I'm having a lot of trouble getting a nice solution to this problem.

I want to export a handout for a beamer presentation using org-mode. I can write a note using `\note{sample note}`, which creates a separate notes page, but I can't have line breaks in the note and I can't do `\note[itemize]{\item ...}` either. Not sure what's going on here. But I would like the slide on the top half of the page and the notes on the bottom (which aren't displayed on the slide). Below is the sample code.

```
#+startup: beamer
#+LaTeX_CLASS: beamer
#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [handout]
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{pgfpages}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \mode<handout>{\setbeameroption{show notes} \pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of a slide with a note:

```
 * Slide
  - Item 1 
  - item 2

 ** Note
 :PROPERTIES:
 :BEAMER_ENV: note
 :END:

 This is a note.
```

IOW, a second level section with a BEAMER_ENV property with a value of "note" becomes a beamer note.

Whether this will get printed out properly the way you want, I don't know.

EDIT: if you look at the tex file that is produced when you export the above,
the Note section becomes

```
\note{Note
 This is a note.}
```

You can leave out the "Note" in the org file:

```
** 
:PROPERTIES:
:BEAMER_ENV: note
:END:

This is a note.
```

Then the tex file shows:

```
\note {
 This is a note.}
```

I'm not sure whether newlines are important in a `\note` environment, but I suspect they are not (they are unimportant in most tex environments I believe).

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to hide the title too? i.e. just show 'This is a note.' and note 'Note'.

Comment: Edited the queston.